# Built-in Speaker doesn't work after installing JACK

Tags: pulseaudio, jack, audio-jack

I am in Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS with lowlatency kernel. Before I installed JACK, everything worked fine, both audio jack and built-in laptop's speakers.

After I installed JACK, the audio jack worked fine while I plugged my earphone in. But when I do not plug the output things through audio jack there is no sound anymore from built-in speakers.

I am using Cadence for configuring JACK. I also use PulseAudio. The image below shows my JACK settings. In Input/Output device, i choose my laptop's default audio card.

Your solutions will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need "pulseaudio to jack bridge" to get pulseaudio and jack work nicely together. Have a look at how Ubuntustudio has done it. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/ProAudioIntro